# Can someone on xbox 360 play gta 5 online with someone on xbox one?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Can someone on xbox 360 play gta 5 online with someone on xbox one? They said its not possible for any game but thats a lie i played with a friend he has xbox one and i have 360.

Answer (score 1):

For GTA V, no it's not possible.  The only games it would be possible with is if your friend with the Xbox One has a game that is on the [Xbox One Backwards Compatability List](https://majornelson.com/blog/xbox-one-backward-compatibility/) that you also have. GTA V is not one of those games.